# how to convert a value inside a dataTable to string in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

The code below is to retrieve a category for a particular id. it will only return just one value say "Sport" to the dataTable. How to i convert the dataTable value to a string. I want to make use of this value for other things in the application

```
var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ToString());
                    conn.Open();
                    var da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Product_Category from Product 
            where 
                     Product_Id =" + fo, conn);
                     da.Fill(mydata);
                     conn.Close();
```

Comment: Use SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar Method () https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: ToString() might be of help

Comment: I can't tell if myData is a DataSet or DataTable.  Here is solution : List<string> results = mydata.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("Select Product_Category")).ToList(); or List<string> results = mydata.Table[0].AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("Select Product_Category")).ToList();

Comment: if you have single column in datatable than you may check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use below code

```
string Product_Category = String.Empty;
if(mydata.Rows.Count>0)
{
Product_Category = mydata.Rows[0]["Product_Category"].ToString();
}
```

Assuming that mydata is DataTable here.

Comment: made mistake with the code. mydata is a DataTable. I will check out your answer now

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single column in `datatable` than it's simple to change `datatable` to `string`.

```
DataTable results = MyMethod.GetResults(); // i am getting data from getresult function
if(results != null && results.Rows.Count > 0)  // Check datatable is null or not
{
  List<string> lstring = new List<string>();
  foreach(DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows)
  {
     lstring.Add(Convert.ToString(dataRow["ColumnName"]));
  }
  string mainresult = string.Join(",", lstring.ToArray()); // You can Use comma(,) or anything which you want. who connect the two string. You may leave space also.
}
Console.WriteLine (mainresult);
```